# Use data import for update revenue

Tags: google-analytics

I have problem with integration our crm system with google analitycs. We want to use offline revenue tracking. We use google tag manager. I setup new Ecommerce tag, and as i see - it works fine. After that I created new data in admin panel with this options

[image]

My example csv file:

```
ga:transactionId,ga:productSku,ga:transactionRevenue,ga:quantityRefunded
1433493048,a1d7311f2a312426d710e1c617fcbc8c,28000,1
1433494861,a1d7311f2a312426d710e1c617fcbc8c,29000,1
1433500564,a1d7311f2a312426d710e1c617fcbc8c,30000,1
1433501589,b440509a0106086a67bc2ea9df0a1dab,31000,1
1433505297,405e28906322882c5be9b4b27f4c35fd,32000,1
```

I uploaded file, and status is "Completed". No errors and no alerts.
But in Reporting panel data not updated.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refund data upload is for, well, refunding.

One guess is that Google Analytics does not want to refund more money than people have actually paid. If you want to import transactions I suggest you use the measurement protocol to send transaction data.

Also your example csv is wrong: the third field is supposed to be the product price, not transaction revenue (so look into the individual transactions to see if the number has been recorded as product price. Analytics does not automatically sum up product prices in a transaction as transaction revenue, you have to pass that in yourself).